# Function with some property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

A function $f$ is defined on the set $\{0,1,2,3,…,n-1\}$ to itself. This is such a function that if you take any $k$ from the set $\{0,1,2,3,…,n-1\}$ then $f^m (k)=0$ for some natural number $m$.

There are exactly $n^{n-1}$ many functions with the said property.

Next question is how many of the functions (with the property) are there, which are monotonically decreasing?

Example: for $n=3$, $f(0)=0,f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=1$.

Comment: Hint: it is necessary and sufficient that $f(x) < x$ for all $x > 0$.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely true.

Comment: So you can set $f(n-1)$ to any of $n-1$ different possibilities.  Then, you can set $f(n-2)$ to any of $n-2$ different possibilities.  Do you see where this is going?

Comment: True. But what is the number of such functions and how that can be proved. Please help. I am too bad in combinatorics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f$ to be monotonoically decreasing and have the property that $f^m(x) = 0$ for some $m$ and all $x$, it is necessary and sufficient for $f(x) < x$ (except, obviously, $f(0) = 0$).

This reduces to a combinatorics problem: $f(n-1)$ can map to any of $n-1$ elements ($0$ through $n-2$), $f(n-2)$ can map to any of $n-2$ elements, etc.  So the total number of functions that satisfy your properties is $(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(3)(2)(1) = (n-1)!$